# jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js throwing an error 'this.source is not function'

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

I am  using  'jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js' for  auto-complete.But it  throwing an error 'TypeError: this.source is not a function'

Html code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="srchfname" auto-complete>
```

Code of  AngularJs

```
app.directive('autoComplete', ['$http',function($http) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({ source: $http
            .get('rest/getFirstName?cd='+(new Date()).getTime())

        });
    }

 }}])
```

When page loads above 'get' request fires succussfully(I have checked in firebug).

Spring code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFirstName",  method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<String> getFirstName() {
               List<String> FnameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<MyList.size();i++)
        {
            FnameList.add(MyList.get(i).getFirstName());
        }
        return FnameList;
    }
```

MyList is  already populated with hard coded data.
please  tell me  where  i go wrong

Comment: might be because you are assigning a promise to `source` not a datasource(string/array)...

Comment: could you elaborate i am new to these technologies

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7y4pp/1/

Comment: i tried  but it did not work. and what is  'source: function (request, response) {response(source) }'  ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  Function for  'source' option i use  'String' option and it work for me.And also made changes in  spring  controller.

directive code

```
source: "rest/getFirstName"
```

Spring code

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFirstName",  method = RequestMethod.GET, produces   = "application/json" ,params="term")
public @ResponseBody
List<String> getFirstName(@RequestParam("term") String term) 
      {
      }
```

and  rest of code  is same.